# What's the pythonic way of using a source url to create a new url with different path and scheme?

Tags: python

Say I have a url that or may not be HTTPS, and who's host name I don't control, but follows a format like:
  http://example.com/special/content    [OR]
  https://example.com/special/content

Using Python what would be the pythonic way of changing scheme to https and path to /something/else

My current approach is:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit, urljoin, urlunsplit
currenturl = "http://example.com/some/content"
parts = list(urlsplit(urljoin(currenturl, "/something/else")))
parts[0]="https"
newurl = urlunsplit(parts)
```

Any suggestions ?

---

Suggestion (from @ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

```
from urlparse import urlparse, urljoin, urlunparse
currenturl = "http://example.com/some/content"
parts = list(urlparse(currenturl))
parts[0]="https"
parts[2]="/something/else"  # If only path needed changing (or see bellow...)
newurl = urlunparse(parts)
newurl = urljoin(newurl, "/something/else") # If we need to rewrite everything
                                            # after network loc
```

Comment: Please note that the urlparse module has been renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are so close. Use `urlparse.urlparse()` to split it up, take the parts you care about, and then use `urlparse.urlunparse()` to put it back together.

Comment: What would be the difference in this case?

Comment: @Mark: One would be brute force, and the other would be Pythonic.

Comment: I meant why particularly did you suggest using `urlparse`/`urlunparse` rather than `urlsplit`/`urlunsplit` - the only difference from the documentation seems to be the handling of parameters, which doesn't seem to be an issue here.